# Simple Java Method Error when Returning

Tags: java

I'm learning methods and was trying to write code that basically tells if a number is prime. However, I keep encountering the error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
                return(isPrime);
                       ^
error: illegal start of type
                return(isPrime);
```

This is my current code (i hope i'm using the method correctly):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoublePalindromicPrimes{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number:");
        int n = in.nextInt();

        //prime(n);
        boolean resultPrime = prime(n);
        if (resultPrime){
            System.out.println("This is a prime");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("This is not a prime");
        }
    }

    public static boolean prime(int x){
        for (int i=2;i<x;i++){
        boolean isPrime;
            if (x%i==0){
                isPrime=false;
            }
            else{
                isPrime=true;
            }
        }
        return isPrime;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I posted an answer to your compilation error, but your `prime` method still has a big logic error; you need a "latch" (a boolean value that stays `false` once you find a factor). It would be simpler to just `return false` immediately if you find a factor, and return `true` otherwise. (Also, you only have to check from `2` to `sqrt(x)`!)

Comment: You declare `isPrime` inside the `for` loop, so it doesn't exist outside that loop when you try to return it. Using good indentation practices and putting braces around your `if`-`else` statements will make your code much easier to read, and you won't miss things like this as often.

Comment: Please don't change the question like you did here. You've corrected the compile errors, which means that the answers you've received no longer make sense.

Comment: @chrylis So i assume I should just add the return statement inside the if statement in the method. I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: @pburka thanks for the tip. I added the original error back. I meant to only update the code with proper indentation.

Comment: @user2913669 Check my edited answer.  Should solve your logic issue.

Comment: I removed the else statement in the for loop and added a return value if the prime number is false. This works. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @LajosArpad Thank you for your feedback, but his code works. Please see my explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static boolean isPrime(int x)
{   
    if(x > 2) {
        if(x%2 == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            int sqrt = (int)(Math.sqrt(x));
            for(int i=3;i<=sqrt;i+=2) {
                if(x%i == 0) {
                     return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else if(x==2) {
        return true;
    } else { //1, 0, and negatives
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is probably equivalent to what the OP intended, it is not a correct test for primality.

Comment: The OP didn't ask about his logic.  He asked about a compiler error.  The answer I provided is logically equivalent to the OP's original question and solves the compiler error, which he asked about.

Comment: Thank you for your response +1. Would you mind giving me a hint where my logic error lies?

Comment: @user2913669 I think my new edit actually fixes your logic error too.

Comment: @pburka Although the user's original question didn't pertain to his logic, my answer seems to be logically correct now, so you can remove your downvote.

Comment: This is very helpful. I realize my error was basically that I didn't need the else if statement within the for loop. +1, however I'm going to leave the current "correct answer" since this isn't a direct answer to my original problem. Thank you though.

Comment: Well, for starters, you haven't accepted any answers.  But my original answer corrected your issue, plus this answer gets around the issue (and improves your code) by completely removing the `isPrime` variable you were having trouble `return`ing in your original question.  This answer 1) fixes your original question, 2) fixes your logic, 3) improves your code.

Comment: Oh it must have have accepted the answer at the time since I can only accept answers after 5 minutes of creating the question. You have a good point. I will select your answer then.

Comment: I am sorry I had to down-vote you. You are going with the index until it reaches x's value, which is slow. Normally I would not down-vote your answer because of this bug, but you have an ERROR in your code as well. 2 is a prime number. What would be the return value of prime(2)? FALSE, because 2 % 2 == 0. Start your cycle from 3.

Comment: Sorry, start your iteration from 2, but before that check whether x == 2

Comment: @LajosArpad actually, his code works because if you start at i = 2, then i<2, which means the for loop is skipped entirely and it returns true (the number is prime).

Comment: Please, see my answer, it is a faster solution.

Comment: That's actually the code I ended up using. Except, you don't even need to create the variable squareRoot. You can call Math.sqrt(x) right inside the for loop.

Comment: @LajosArpad Since there's such a concern for optimization, for whatever reason, my answer has been edited and is now a bit more optimized.  The idea of using squareroot is extremely problematic in the case of `x = 9`.  (And negative numbers)

Comment: @user2913669 Calling `Math.sqrt(x)` inside the loop is problematic for two reasons.  First, it's less optimal than creating a variable to store the square root and only call `Math.sqrt(x)` once, because you're calling it once per loop iteration and this takes processing time.  And second, now you get the wrong result for `x = 9` and an exception for any negative numbers.  And finally, calling `Math.sqrt(x)` takes the same number of loop iterations as not calling `Math.sqrt(x)`.  Not calling it saves the processing time it takes to call it.

Comment: @LajosArpad Edited my answer to now include the `sqrt` optimization.

Answer (score 3):

change it to

```
return isPrime;
```

note the space and make declaration out of `isPrime` for loop

Comment: This answer implies that the parentheses are the problem. They are unnecessary, but harmless.

Answer (score 2):

You declared `isPrime` inside your loop, so the `return` statement can't see it. Move it outside the loop.

Comment: i moved `boolean prime;` outside of the for loop. now the error says: `error: variable isPrime might not have been initialized`

Comment: @user2913669 That's because `boolean isPrime;` *declares* the variable but does not actually create it. You need to give it a "default" value: e.g. the value it should return if I call `prime(2)` (this won't enter the loop, but you still need to decide what value to return).

Comment: Thank you! I added `boolean isPrime=false;` and it compiles. However, my logic seems to have an error. It does not actually detect primes :S

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean prime(int x) //throws InvalidNumberException
{
    if (x <= 0)
    {
        //throw new InvalidNumberException("The number is invalid");
    }
    int squareRoot = (int)(Math.sqrt(x));
    for (int i = 2; i <= squareRoot; i++)
    {
        if (x % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is an optimized prime validator.

Comment: This works too and I ended up with something like this. Thank you for submitting it. Although I would like to point out the you can call Math.sqrt(x) right inside the for loop.

Comment: That is true, but it is not ideal. Think about it. If you call it outside the for loop, then you calculate it only once, whereas if you calculate it inside the for loop, then you calculate it a lot of times. So this time I was right and the score is 1-1 :)

Comment: You're right haha. I assume you're referring to the speed when processing many intergers?

Comment: Yes, x is a big number compared to squareRoot, so if we iterate until we reach x, then we work a lot more without a reason. If you call prime 10000 times with big numbers as input, then you will feel the difference. Also, calculating squareRoot is a relatively slow operation, but if we calculate it once, then the amount of time we lose is insignificant, whereas if we calculate it on each iteration, then it will slow down the algorithm. Also, calculating once squareRoot is fast compared to iterating until we reach x.

Comment: If you want to truly optimize, check `%2` before entering the loop, have the loop start at `3` and count by `2`s.  Once you've checked `2`, you don't need to check any other even number.

Comment: @nhgrif, it seems you are missing the point. We always have to think about infinity when we optimize. sqrt(9) = 3, true, but sqrt(1000000) = 1000, so if we are checking a prime near 1000000, then you will have 1000x more interations. It is not the same to have O(sqrt(n)) complexity as to have O(n) complexity. 3 is a trivial prime, it does not really matter whether you have a square root or not, as it is of constant complexity.

Comment: Yeah, <= should have been instead of <. Fixed.

Comment: @LajosArpad I'm removing my comments that I now see were incorrect.  Though, I'll add back that your solution still throws an exception on negative numbers (should just return false if x<2).  And the one thing I was right about (numbers whose roots are prime) has now been fixed.  (And I changed my downvote to an upvote)

Comment: That is not a bug, it is a feature. We can agree that in no normal circumstances would a sane person call this method with negative numbers. So if anybody calls the method with negative numbers, then it is a bug. And an exception is thrown which shows the exact location of the bug through the stack-trace. So it is more about coding style, I am more on the philosophical stance of expecting programmers to use my methods correctly and automatically letting them know if they are mis-using any of my methods.

Comment: Then I'd argue it's still better to explicitly throw a exception that describes what the problem is.  If I call your `prime` method with a negative number, and get an exception explaining that I can't `sqrt` negative numbers, I'd be mightily confused.

Comment: I might implement that, right now I need a good sleep after a looong working day.

Comment: Thank you, I slept well indeed :)